# Meaning of "Get it? Got it? Good."

Tags: phrase-meaning

This phrase originated from *The Court Jester* ([link to 2-second clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KM1VXhZT37E)).

> **Hubert Hawkins:** I'd like to get in, get on with it, get it over with, and get out. Get it?
>
> **Ravenhurst:** Got it.
>
> **Hubert Hawkins:** Good.

However, I have seen it being used as a phrase—"Get it? Got it? Good" ([example on YouTube](https://youtu.be/q7ASGB-uWTk?t=1m37s)).

What does it mean as a phrase said by one individual, and what are some examples of when one would use this phrase?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why this is being closed. Two users think it doesn't show enough research, yet when I google its meaning, *this very EL&U question* comes up top! There are **no** easily available resources that adequately address the contemporary usage of this question. And the 3rd closure reason ("primarily opinion-based") seems bizarre! I'm voting to leave it open, as it makes a valuable contribution not just to our site but to the available corpus of online resources on English usage. :-)

Comment: The line is actually a running gag in the 1955 film: in the [film script](http://ec.intranet.org/home/play/court_jester.html) I count five separate occasions when it's used. You can see another occasion at about the 12-second mark in this [2-minute clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cysxO5Z-0L8). My guess is that the line became more popular when the film gained a new generation of enthusiasts after it became a staple on TV in the '70s.

Comment: It is also used in the film “The Producers” by Mel Brooks, at least in the 2005 version, anyhow.

Comment: Please describe how it's used in the video, with background info if possible. Videos are taken down a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all depends on where you put question marks and exclamation marks (or fullstops).
 You can have all the four combinations: interrogative-affirmative, interrogative-interrogative, affirmative-affirmative, affirmative-interrogative.

The first example, interrogative-affirmative, which requires two persons:

> A: Get it? B: Got it. A: Good.

means:

*A: Do you understand it? B: I understood it. A: Good (I'm glad).*

---

The youtube example you provided, interrogative-interrogative, requires just one person speaking:

> Get it? Got it? Good.

means:

*Do you understand it? Did you understand it? Good (I'm glad).*

---

Affirmative-affirmative, requires two persons:

> A: Get it. B: Got it. A: Good.

it means:

*A: Obtain it (command). B: I obtained it. A: Good.*

---

Affirmative-interrogative, requires one person:

> Get it. Got it? Good.

it means:

*Obtain it (command). Did you obtain it? Good.*

Answer (score 3):

[***Get It-Got It-Good***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7647682/) was a British children's TV quiz show back in **1967**, as per that IMDB link.

[Here's](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hdFRAQAAMAAJ&q=%22Get+it+Got+it+Good%22&dq=%22Get+it+Got+it+Good%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBj72k9IniAhVMUxUIHZzqCTwQ6AEIKjAA) a written instance from the *Radio Times*, when it was scheduled after the far better known *Jackanory*.

It's probably not really worth trying to pin down an exact "meaning" for the collocation. Mostly I'd say it's just a typical "three-part catchy name", similar to, for example, *Ready, Steady, Go!* (a British pop music show from around the same time).

Answer (score 1):

My answer is only based on the video you posted, as this is the meaning you're after.

---

He's asking the viewer whether or not they understood what was said. Obviously, a viewer can't respond to a video (even though a lot of children keep trying), so the speaker doesn't wait for an answer from the viewer.

It's similar to *"[...], savvy?"* (as often said by [Captain Jack Sparrow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8UbKMXZQKE)). It is a rhetorical question, implying that the previous statement is important and **needs to be remembered**.

Note that it's possible to use this in a non-rhetorical sense (when you expect the other person to actually confirm that they understood it), but this is impossible for a Youtube video since you're not having a conversation with the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase was popular in the late 80s early 90s. It is typically proceeded by a plan, action, or how the speaker thinks things should go. When they finish with the phrase, it means they aren't kidding around or there is no choice in the matter. For example a parent might have told their kid, "you will be grounded if you don't clean their room. Get it? Got it? Good!" Another example would be A, "we're heading to the park to play basketball." B, "I don't want to." A, "we are playing basketball. Get it? Got it? Good."

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's lacking two things: detail on *where* it was used (India? Cornwall? New Orleans?), and if possible, supporting evidence such as a published example.  An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. Can you [edit] your answer to provide more information? For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: I don't know about "popular in the late 80s early 90s". For the 25 years *since* 1995, Google Books has [7 hits.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Get+it+Got+it+Good%22&biw=1427&bih=744&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1995%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2099&tbm=bks) But there are just [6 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Get+it+Got+it+Good%22&biw=1427&bih=744&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1970%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1994&tbm=bks) for the *preceding* 25 years.

Comment: @FumbleFingers of course one of the deficiencies of a book search is that it's unlikely to capture the extent of *spoken usage* of an expression, and in this particular case, a search can be further complicated by the variable punctuation *within* the expression. Nonetheless, your links provide quite useful additional data - could I humbly suggest you edit your own answer to add this information? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Example of use in media:

Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles II (The secret of the ooze) - 1991

Leonardo: "Guys, huddle, huddle, c'mere, c'mon! Mikey, you go up the middle. You guys take the sides. Get it?"

Donatello: "Got it."

Raphael "Good."

Michelangelo: "I don't get it."

After which Mikey does in fact go up the middle. He then headbutts the big Footclan ninja in the gut, causing the ooze canister to fly out of his hands and into the air. Donnie deftly catches it and proceeds to ride an office chair like a surfboard, only to be wiped out by a Footclan's Bo. The canister is once again sent through the air, but is this time caught by the villain Tatsu who exclaims "Ninja vanish!". Tatsu then tosses a smoke bomb at the turtles and swiftly disappears along with the other Footclan ninjas. It is in this way that the turtles loose the last canister, which is then used by the Foot to create Tokka and Rahzar, the mutants who consider Shredder to be their "Mamma".

This movie is, by the way, truly excellent.